# How to create a bidirectional edge between two vertices using gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin

What is the best way to create a bidirectional edge between two vertices using gremlin. Is there a direct command which adds the edge or should we add two edges like vertex X -> Vertex Y and vertex Y -> Vertex X?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add an edge between two vertices and then ignore the direction at query-time by using the `both()` step. This is how you typically address bidirectional edges in Gremlin.

Let's open the Gremlin Console and create a simple graph where Alice and Bob are friends:

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard())
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> 
==>null
gremlin> g.addV(label, 'user', 'name', 'Alice').as('alice').addV(label, 'user', 'name', 'Bob').as('bob').addE('friendWith').from('alice').to('bob')
==>e[4][0-friendWith->2]
```

This creates a graph with two vertices and one edge:

```
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[4][0-friendWith->2]
```

Notice how you cannot traverse from the Bob vertex to the Alice vertex in the outgoing direction, but you can traverse in the ingoing direction (first query yields no result).

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Bob').out('friendWith')
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Bob').in('friendWith')
==>v[0]
```

Or starting from Alice (second query yields no result), you get the opposite:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Alice').out('friendWith')
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Alice').in('friendWith')
```

However, you can traverse the graph in both directions with the `both()` step, and retrieve Alice's friend or Bob's friend.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Alice').both('friendWith')
==>v[2]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'Bob').both('friendWith')
==>v[0]
```

This would also work on more complex graphs with more than two vertices and one friendship relationship. The `both()` step simply ignores the direction of the edges when attempting to traverse to adjacent vertices.